# Sending touch event to another application

Tags: touch, external, simulation

I am able to launch an app from my code but am not able to send touch simulation to the button in that app.. Here is the main code. There are no errors when compiling. I had used dispatchevent but since that didn't work I removed it

```
package com.mycompany.myapp3;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.*;
import android.system.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.InputDevice.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button button;
//static public MotionEvent obtain(long downtime,long eventime,int action,float x,float y,int metastate)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnbutton();
    
        simulatepress(-1100,250);

       MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,400,400,0);



    }


public void addListenerOnbutton() {

button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){
Intent launchIntent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.abc.xyz");
if (launchIntent!=null){
startActivity(launchIntent);
}

pause1(10000);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Waiting over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    simulatepress(-180,25);

}
});


}
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
// TODO: Implement this method
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
    


public void pause1(long sleeptime){
try{
Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
} catch (InterruptedException ex){

}
}


// our program for generating click
// dont delete


public void simulatepress(long x,long y){
MotionEvent e=MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x,y,0);
onTouchEvent(e);
//dispatchTouchEvent(e);

}










}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a root method:

```
String x,y = "400"
String[] deviceCommands = {"su", "input touchscreen tap", x, y};
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(deviceCommands);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Only works with root. x and y are the coordinates.