# How to get a view from new activity intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build an app that tap on screen on anothr app. I found this code:

```
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

I opened the another app by it's package name:

```
Intent i =getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.shazam.android");
startActivity(i);
```

but I did't secceed to get it's view object.

how can I get the view object?

Comment: Does this package have a documentation ? What is the context of the code you found ? Does it apply to given package ? You should be more specific for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, you want to dispatch a touch event in another app.

In this case, I am sorry to tell you, that something like this is not possible on a regular Android-Device.

If your device has root-access, then you could try using the approach described by @konraditurbe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096982/4773698)